# Creating data that follows a specific data distribution

Tags: distributions, python, random-generation

I have a variable z which has around 3000 values between 0.0 and 0.5.

I have plotted here z in the y-axis and 3000 evenly spaced numbers over the interval 0.0 and 0.5 in the x-axis so that one can see my data distribution.

[image]

I want to create another set of data of 100,000 points, **that follows the distribution of my original data, i.e z**.

How can I do this? Preferably in Python?

Comment: There are many ways to generate random variates. Some of them capitalize on mathematical relationships determined by formulas for the distribution functions. Others only need a list of data such as you used to draw that fitted curve. If you have a formula for the distribution function, consider quoting it so that readers can determine whether it will be useful for your purpose.

Comment: @Glen_b But the function seems to fit the histogram! I donno how. I want to create a data set of 100,000 points that follow my data distribution. Is there a way to do this apart from my idea, which I am not sure is right or wrong!

Comment: You can truncate the domain of your density function where it becomes negative. However, would every other scientist take the same fitting density for your data? Data analysis has to be reproducible. Are there reasons for taking this particular rational function? What if one decides to take a function with 3 parameters to fit?

Comment: Why do you need smoothed random data?

Comment: @Glen_b I am using these randoms to calculate two point correlation functions. So if I take the fluctuations of my data into account, the correlation function would be disturbed. So I want smooth random, like the curve above

Comment: The curve is smooth, but in what sense do you mean that it's random?

Comment: I think the word random is misleading. I will use data instead

Comment: @Srivastan: Instead of correlation one can use nonparametric measures, in particular Spearman's rank correlation. This does not change if the data are monotonically transformed, so you would not have to worry about the shape of the distribution any more. However, I've not yet understood between which random variables you want to consider the correlation. I suggest to ask a new question about this correlation issue and to leave the resampling question as it was.

Answer (score 3):

Numerically you have to choose a nonnegative function $f$ with integral 1. This is the density of your probabiliy distribution, and statistically, this part is the most difficult. You can find a lot about density estimation. Then you invert $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)\mathrm{d}z$. Next you generate a pseudo random number, say $y$, from the interval $[0,1]$. `random.uniform` in Python does this step. Your desired random numbers then are $F^{-1}(y)$.

Note however that scientifically this is rarely useful. The density you chose to fit is arbitrary, right? Why not take something different? It will fit the data better or worse, but you don't know what this means because typically you don't know the true distribution of your data. This will happen with all choices of beautiful density functions.

So another approach is to chose the value of any of your observations with equal probability: `z[random.choice(1:2700)]` These random numbers will have exactly the distribution you observed. This approach is called resampling. The drawback of this approach is that the tails of your distribution are underestimated. Even if extreme observations have a high probability to occur in the real distribution, the probability to get an observation more extreme than in your original data is 0. If this is crucial, don't choose this approach.